# How to check if a date is between specific days compared using the TODAY() function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to check several timeframes of dates compared to today's date. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with my formula. I have revised it several times and recently added the `AND` function. Does anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Formula:

`=IF(E10>(TODAY()), "Schedule CPD Presentation asap and consider changing sales start date", IF(AND(E10 <= (TODAY()-1,E10< TODAY() +10), "Query 1", "Query 2")))`

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1695462/edit) to include the formula as text? It would also be useful to know what the content of `E10` is. And if it is a date, have you checked that it is, indeed a date and not a string?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Sure, I just edited my question.

Comment: I believe `...IF(AND(E10 <= (TODAY()-1...` should be `...IF(AND(E10 <= TODAY()-1...` (remove the `(` before `TODAY`)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks! That was it. I put the AND function in to try to get the formula to work but in my second if statement if I just wanted to check if today's value is between -1 and 10 compared to the date of E10, can I do so without the ANd? Because I really only want one returned result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's split up your formula so you can find the error.

```
=IF(
    E10>(TODAY()),
    "Schedule CPD Presentation asap and consider changing sales start date",
    IF(
       AND(
           E10 <= (TODAY()-1,E10< TODAY() +10),
           "Query 1",
           "Query 2"
          )
      )
   )
```

That's not what you want. The error is on this line:

```
E10 <= (TODAY()-1,E10< TODAY() +10),
```

You haven't matched your parentheses correctly. The entire `AND()` statement should be like this:

```
AND(E10<=TODAY()-1,E10<TODAY()+10)
```

... but yours is like this:

```
AND(E10<=(TODAY()-1,E10<TODAY()+10)
```

The extra parentheses before the first `TODAY()` throws everything off so the `AND()` function isn't getting something it can deal with. If you delete that one parentheses (and one at the end), your formula looks like this:

```
=IF(E10>(TODAY()), "Schedule CPD Presentation asap and consider changing sales start date", IF(AND(E10 <= TODAY()-1,E10< TODAY() +10), "Query 1", "Query 2"))
```

... which can be broken out like this:

```
=IF(
    E10>(TODAY()),
    "Schedule CPD Presentation asap and consider changing sales start date",
    IF(
       AND(
           E10 <= TODAY()-1,
           E10< TODAY() +10
          ),
       "Query 1",
       "Query 2"
      )
   )
```

Comment: Thanks! I put the AND function in to try to get the formula to work but in my second if statement if I just wanted to check if today's value is between -1 and 10 compared to the date of E10, can I do so without the AND? Because I really only want one returned result. The `AND` second result is actually interfering with my initial if statement.

Comment: The way the formula is written now is not returning the results you want, I think. You want to check if `E10-TODAY()` is between -1 and 10 but the first `IF()` already covers all cases where `E10>TODAY()` so the second `IF()` is only going to capture those where `E10-TODAY()` is between -1 and 0. You may want to ask a new question to address the "not getting the results you expect" part.